# Selecting specific element from a list of lists based on values of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of pairs in which every pair correspond to a edge in a network (or graph). This list in a .txt file (available here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-1l3__IxJ8qe_wtM4_0TYuklwoH_Rqa/view?usp=sharing). What I have to do is select a random number of nodes in the network and then extract from the list above the edges that leave and arrive at each node i randomly selected.
I managed to do this with the following code:

```
links = Import["<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-1l3__IxJ8qe_wtM4_0TYuklwoH_Rqa/view?usp=sharing>", "Data"];
totalNodes = Max[First /@ links];
firstNode = Min[First /@ links];
randomNodes = RandomInteger[{firstNode, totalNodes}, 50];
```

Where I use the `Max` and `Min` functions to find the highest and lowest value attributed to a node in order to generate the list of randomly selected nodes using `RandomInteger`. Using the `randomNodes` list I have to find in the `links` list all the edges that go out from the node and also arrive at each of the nodes in `randomNodes`. The code below works fine for me:

```
selectedLinksOut = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Select[links, #[[1]] == Sort[randomNodes][[i]] &], {i, 
     Length[randomNodes]}], 1];

selectedLinksIn = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Select[links, #[[2]] == Sort[randomNodes][[i]] &], {i, 
     Length[randomNodes]}], 1];

finalLinks = Join[selectedLinksIn, selectedLinksOut];
```

But even for this set of data, which has about 25000 edges it takes a little bit to do this task. Would there be a way to do this maybe avoiding the use of `Table` to do it faster?

Comment: can you make the file public?

Comment: My bad, I think it's public now

Comment: does `List @@@ IncidenceList[UndirectedEdge @@@ links, 
  Alternatives @@ randomNodes]` give what you need?

Comment: .. or `List @@@ EdgeList[UndirectedEdge @@@ links, 
  UndirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ randomNodes, _]]`?

Comment: Not exactly, this gives me a different output from `finalLinks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
randomNodes = RandomInteger[{firstNode, totalNodes}, 50]
```

You can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) as follows:

```
lIn = Cases[{_, Alternatives @@ randomNodes}]@links;

Sort[lIn] == DeleteDuplicates@Sort[selectedLinksIn]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
lOut = Cases[{Alternatives @@ randomNodes, _}]@links;

Sort[lOut] == DeleteDuplicates@Sort[selectedLinksOut]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
lInOut = Union[lIn, lOut];

lInOut == DeleteDuplicates@Sort[finalLinks]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively,

```
lInOut2 = Cases[{Alternatives @@ randomNodes, _} | {_, Alternatives @@ randomNodes}]@
  links;

lInOut == Sort @ lInOut2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Oh, this one works a lot faster than the one I was using. Thanks ;)